# Problem in updating the contact list in android application

Tags: react-native, react-native-contacts

How exactly the react-native-contacts getAll method works? How frequently it updates the contact list in the application? Is there any particular interval to sync the contact list from the device to the application in android devices??

Answer (score 0):

You can read the source code to understand how it works better https://github.com/morenoh149/react-native-contacts/blob/master/ios/RCTContacts/RCTContacts.m#L197

It should read the latest contacts on every call. There is no interval to sync at. That will depend on what it is exactly that you are building.